# Unrecognized selector sent to instance with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a slideshow app with `swift` but I have a problem,
in `main.storyboard` I add one `imageview` and one button, when the user click on the button the slideshow will animate.

I wrote this code at viewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet var ImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var animateBtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func animateBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    startAnimation()
}

var imageList:[UIImage]=[]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
   for i in 1 ... 3{
        let imagename="\(i).jpg"

    imageList.append(UIImage(named: imagename)!)
    }

}

func startAnimation()->(){
    if !ImageView.isAnimating()
    {
    ImageView.animationImages=[imageList]
        ImageView.startAnimating()
    animateBtn.setTitle("Stop Animation", forState:UIControlState.Normal)}
    else
    {
        ImageView.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

At appdelegate.swift I didn't write any code.

But this app was crashed when I clicked the button and show this message error

```
2014-12-02 09:54:55.693 #4 animation photo[921:613] -[Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f82126615d0
2014-12-02 09:54:55.698 #4 animation photo[921:613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f82126615d0'
```

Comment: What happens if you use `ImageView.animationImages = imageList` instead of `ImageView.animationImages = [imageList]`? I'm not clear on why you seem to be wrapping the array in an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageView`'s `animationImages` property should be an array of `UIImage` objects. What you're actually setting it to is an *array of an array of* `UIImage` objects. That's because you've already got an array:

```
var imageList:[UIImage]=[]
```

...but when you set the property, you wrap this in square brackets, which puts the existing array into another, further array:

```
ImageView.animationImages=[imageList]
```

When the ImageView starts trying to animate the images, it expects each element in its array to be a UIImage, but it instead finds another array. It tries to invoke a UIImage selector, `_isResizable`, on an array object, and that's the error you're seeing:

```
-[Swift._NSSwiftArrayImpl _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f82126615d0
```

So, just don't wrap your array with an array. Set it directly as the property:

```
ImageView.animationImages = imageList
```